# Unable to scroll when wrapping list items with dismissible widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning flutter and I am making use of the `ListView.builder` constructor for displaying a list and when I am just returning the ListItem, I can scroll the items in the listview. but when I wrap the ListItem with a `Dismissible` widget. the scrolling (2 finger scrolling when hovering over the list) stops and I am unable to scroll.

Working code w/o dismissible widget:

```
import 'package:expense_tracker/models/expense.dart';
import 'package:expense_tracker/widgets/expenses_list/expense_item.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpensesList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Expense> expenses;
  final void Function(Expense item) removeItem;
  const ExpensesList(
      {super.key, required this.expenses, required this.removeItem});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: expenses.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return ExpenseItem(
            expense: expenses[index],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Not working code with Dismissible widget:

```
import 'package:expense_tracker/models/expense.dart';
import 'package:expense_tracker/widgets/expenses_list/expense_item.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpensesList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Expense> expenses;
  final void Function(Expense item) removeItem;
  const ExpensesList(
      {super.key, required this.expenses, required this.removeItem});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: expenses.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return Dismissible(
            key: ValueKey(expenses[index]),
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              removeItem(expenses[index]);
            },
            background: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error.withOpacity(0.75),
              // The margin is !
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: Theme.of(context).cardTheme.margin!.horizontal,
              ),
            ),
            child: ExpenseItem(
              expense: expenses[index],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance and Let me know if anything else is needed or I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the screenshot of the app to get an idea
[image: picture of dummy list on right half]

Note: I'm running the app on the emulator with 2gb ram.

> Edit: Adding the expense_item widget

```
import 'package:expense_tracker/models/expense.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpenseItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Expense expense;

  const ExpenseItem({super.key, required this.expense});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              expense.title,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "\$${expense.amount.toStringAsFixed(2)}",
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(categoryIcons[expense.category]),
                    const SizedBox(width: 8),
                    Text(expense.formattedDate)
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try your code with different Dismissible child, and worked perfectly,
scrolling may not work because the child (ExpenseItem),
You might have to add both `shrinkWrap: true, physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()`  in Listview.builder or one of them,

To get more help try updating your question with more code about ExpenseItem Widget,

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just restarted and its scrolling without any changes. One thing I did notice was I had to hold and drag to scroll but I'm used to two finger scroll on my laptop's trackpad to scroll the list which is having this issue when I point the cursor or focus it on the list it doesn't work.